# How can i add a method to mscorelib

Tags: c#, mscorlib

I want to add some methods to mscorlib. For example:

string abc;

abc.IsNumeric()

i hope could explain my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't add methods to mscorlib, however you can use extension methods so they appear as if they are defined on string, e.g.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNumeric(this string s)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Which you can then call as you requested, e.g.

```
"1234".IsNumeric()
```

Answer (score 4):

You got a good answer by Greg. Just wanted to add that you can read more about extension methods here:

- [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)
- [Extension Methods (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)